# Почему не работает отслеживание нажатия клавиш на JS?

Tags: javascript

Набросал небольшой код

```
addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    if (event.which == 49)
      document.getElementById('str').innerHTML="49";
    else if (event.which == 50)
      document.getElementById('str').innerHTML="50";
});

<div id="str"></div>
```

Но не работает. И ещё вопрос, когда лучше применять addEventListener а когда например `window.onkeypress`

Comment: `click` - это событие нажатия на кнопку мыши

Comment: У события `click` нет свойств `which`.

Comment: @Igor а, теперь понятно, спасибо, а есть такое событие для нажатия клавиши?

Comment: keypress https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events

Comment: `window.onkeypress` можно применять когда у вас один обработчик, а при помощи `addEventListener` можно навешивать несколько.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko - есть which - для правой левой и колеса и т.д

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {

  document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = event.keyCode;

  if (event.keyCode == 49)
    document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = "49";
  else if (event.keyCode == 50)
    document.getElementById('str').innerHTML = "50";
});
```

```html
<div id="current">press key</div>
<div id="str"></div>
```